# Ito formula for functions in Sobolev spaces

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I was recently reading a paper (Lumley, R. R., & Zervos, M. (2001). A Model for Investments in the Natural Resource Industry with Switching Costs.) that contains the following statement:

Elements of the Sobolev space $W^{2,p}_{loc}((0,\infty))$, $p\geq 1$, have sufficient smoothness to be able to apply Ito's formula.

Where can I find a proof of this result? There is no reference in the paper. It was also mentioned that $W^{2, \infty}_{loc}((0,\infty))$ can be identified with the function space $C^{1, 1}_{loc}((0,\infty))$, whose elements are continuously differentiable functions with locally Lipschitz first derivatives. What does it mean that 2 spaces can be identified with each other?

Comment: You'll want to look into Sobolev embedding to make sense of this.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your answer. Can you briefly explain how Sobolev embedding theorems relate to this?

Comment: For the second one, Sobolev embedding furnishes one direction of the mapping, and then you can build the other one from scratch. (Sketch: For any compact $K \subset (0,\infty)$, $C^1_1(K)$ functions have one $L^\infty(K)$ first derivative since the first derivative is continuous, and then the Lipschitz property of the first derivative implies that they have an $L^\infty(K)$ weak second derivative, which might have jumps but is still bounded). So now they're identified with each other because this isomorphism exists. It helps with the first one too.

Comment: @Ian From what I understood, $W^{2,p}_{loc}((0,\infty))$ can be identified with functions that are $C^{1}$ with a weak second derivative, not just $W^{2,\infty}_{loc}((0,\infty))$. But I don't see how this applies to the first question, are they applying Ito's formula to the identified function?

Comment: In one dimension, $W^{2,p}$ embeds into $C^{1,1-1/p}$ provided $p>1$. I don't recall the details of how you tie this into using Ito's formula exactly. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76609/generalized-itos-formula seems related albeit probably overkill since you are interested in one dimension.

Comment: @Ian The answer he gives would work for me, but the result is not in the reference he mentions, so Im not sure if it's correct.